# xpages session scope AND document data binding

Tags: data-binding, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a value that I get from a picklist. I set this value as a sessionScope variable.

I then want to use this value, do a lookup, and set the value of an input field - which is working.

However, I am doing the lookup code in the fields data binding section using SSJS, and as such am not too sure how to save this value (normally my data binding would just be document1.FIELDNAME)

I've tried setting the value as part of my code, but the change is not saved in the backend doc.

I've also tried doing the lookup code in the fields "Default value" property, but this always just returns nothing.

Does anyone know how I can display on the xpage the value from my lookup AND also save this value to the backend document?

I fear I am missing something simple and maybe getting tunnel vision!

The code I am using for my data binding value is below.

Thanks

```
try{
var key1 = sessionScope.PLProspectiveAssured;
var dbName:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(database.getServer(),"CIR2001.nsf");

if (key1==""){
returnVal = "Not found";
}else {
var vwOrgs:NotesView = dbName.getView("OrgDocID");
var doc:NotesDocument = vwOrgs.getDocumentByKey(key1);
returnVal = doc.getItemValueString("OrgCountry");
}

// set our field
var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("ProspectiveAssured", returnVal);

return returnVal;

}catch(e){
openLogBean.addError(e,this);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your datasource and set the value using .setValue(field, value). In your case:

```
// set our field
document1.setValue("ProspectiveAssured", returnVal);
```

Make sure that you save your datasource somewhere (else).

Comment: Tunnel vision it was!

Thanks alot Per, all working now, cheers